# Is it mathematically correct to write the primitive of a function in this way : $F(x)=\int f(x)dx$

Tags: integration

Is it mathematically correct to write the primitive of a function in this way :
$F(x)=\int f(x)dx$

or should we absolutely change the variable name : as in $F(t)=\int f(x)dx$ ?
(that is : not use the same variable inside the integral)

Comment: The first one is better form.  Even better: $F(x) = \int f(x)dx + C$.  For example,
$$\cos x = \int \sin x \space dx + C.$$

The second one is more appropriate for definite integrals, for example

$$F(t) = \int_a^t f(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F(x)=\int f(x)dx$ is very common.  So you will never convince everyone not to do it.

However $F(t)=\int f(x)dx$ is worse.  The RHS does not reveal what the variable is.

Some peculiar people may write $F = \int f$, which is OK as far as variables are concerned.

Related:  Do not write $F(x)=\int_0^x f(x)dx$. That has $x$ used for two different things in the same formula.

But it is OK to write $F(t)=\int_0^t f(x)dx$.  This time the RHS does reveal what the variable is.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanations.